# differences between dates in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have two columns namely enddate and startdate
I need to find all those records where

> (enddate-startdate)>2 years

I tried using `timediff(enddate,startdate)>2`

But it returns an error saying : ***'timediff' is not a recognized built-in function name***

I am using sql server management studio,  any help ?

My date format is `2007-04-16 00:00:00.000`

Comment: which sql are you using ? Database and version

Comment: Microsoft sql server management studio 10.0.5500.0

Comment: @Naga: that is your ***client*** software, it doesn't tell us which version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: how do I get the database version then?

Comment: What do you mean by two years?  is Jan 1 2010 - Dec 31 2011 only one year ? Is Dec 31 2010 to Jan1 2012  two years ?  or do you mean 24 months ? or do you mean calendar day to calendar day ?

Comment: Is it sqlexpress 11.0.2218 ?

Comment: @CharlesBretana I mean the difference should be greater than 24 months

Comment: @Naga,  then Feb 1 2010 to Jan 31 2012 would fail, but Jan 31 2010 to Jan 1 2012 would pass ?  i.e.,  the date in the month does not matter ?

Comment: I am not sure about that @CharlesBretana , you can tell me what to do looking at the format of the dates I have, I think the total difference should be 24 months inclusive of dates

Comment: @Naga, What should it do if one year is leap year? Should Mar1 2010 to Feb29 2012 count ?

Comment: @Naga,  the question is what to "count" months?  Days?  Or hours, Minutes ? or seconds?  What ?  SQL Server can "count the number of datetime boundaries between any two datetinme values, or it can calculate the acdtual time interval, and, regardless of when it starts and stops, see if it's greater than 2 x 365 x 24 x60 x 60 seconds.  What exactly does your application need ?

Comment: All the datediff function variants do is count the number of date boundaries you must cross to get from one datetinme tot the other.  Dec 31 2010 to Jan1 2011 is only one day, but `datediff(year, 'dec 31 2010', '1 jan 2011')` will return One Year

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use `DateDiff`

```
DateDiff(year,enddate,startdate)
```

Comment: what does mi stand for?

Comment: @Naga It's mean minutes

Comment: I want the one where difference is in years, and if I use your command as DateDiff(mi,enddate,startdate) >2 , it is still giving me records where the difference is less than 2 years

Comment: So change it to `year` I thought you want to time not year :)

Comment: @Naga this will not find rows with 2 or more year difference, this will find rows where the year of enddate and the year of startdate is more than 2 years apart

Comment: This is wrong.  It will pass if start is `31 dec 2010` and end is `1 jan 2012`, even though those two dates are only 12 months and one day apart.  If @Naga wants to check for 24 months, then `datediff(year ....`  will NOT work.

Answer (score 6):

```
WHERE dateadd(year, -2, enddate) > startdate
```

Comment: mysql has ADDDATE not dateadd

Comment: who said this was mysql ?

Comment: it is NOT mysql but MSSQL

Comment: this still gives me records with a difference less than 2 years

Comment: why not `enddate > dateadd(year, 2, startdate)` ?

Answer (score 3):

I would use `DATEDIFF`.  It should get you there at a macro level.

```
DECLARE @orderTracker TABLE (
    orderDate DATE,
    orderShipped DATE,
    orderNum VARCHAR(6)
);


INSERT INTO @orderTracker
        ( orderDate, orderShipped, orderNum )
    VALUES ('01/01/2012', '06/12/2013', '55YY7'),
        ('05/20/2006', '09/10/2008', 'sdlhf8'),
        ('06/02/2011', '10/12/2012', '34JJU'),
        ('11/25/2009', '06/12/2013', '553iSS'),
        ('06/15/2008', '12/12/2011', '5F09U7'),
        ('02/06/2013', '08/12/2013', '55YY7');

SELECT * FROM @orderTracker;

SELECT *
FROM @orderTracker
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, orderDate, orderShipped) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(year, startdate, enddate) > 2
```

EDIT: Duplicated, I had not seen the answer of Jayesh Goyani, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

From discussion in comments, your best bet is to establish a threshold date using the start datetime and dateAdd function.  This will give you all records where the end time is after the datetime at the same time of day, on the same calendar date (month, day of month), two years after the start date.

```
Where endDate > dateadd(year, 2, startDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use 'Year' in DateDiff

```
 DATEDIFF(year, startdate, enddate) > 2
```

For more information please check below link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This should return the number of years:

```
DATEDIFF(year,'2008-06-05','2008-08-05')
```

Answer (score 0):

DATEDIFF does **not** work correctly for this situation as of the time of me writing this. Actually, it doesn't work correctly at all and no one should use it.

Example being;

```
    DATEDIFF(YEAR, '2016-08-28', '2017-04-28')
```

Returns 1, although it has **not** been a year. It simply subtracts the years and doesn't take into account the months or days.

Use the DATEADD method instead, as others have suggested.